# Python Selenium find element and return HTML tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python Selenium to find an element within the following HTML...

```
<div id="results">
    <h1>Results</h1>
    <p>These Are The Results</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Result 1</li>
        <li>Result 2</li>
        <li>Result 3</li>
        <li>Result 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#results").text
```

This works correctly but the data it returns does not include the HTML tags, is there a way I can make it return the HTML tags as well as the data with the #results div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get HTML, you have to get attribute 'outerHTML' or 'innerHTML'.  The outerHTML will include HTML of current element. See code below:

```
htmlText = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#results").get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

Comment: @alecxe if you take a look at answered time, you will see that I answered this before you 3 minutes.

Comment: @alecxe I'm new to stack exchange, could you tell me if you should delete your answer or not?

Comment: apologies, you are right, sorry for the tone - will delete the answer, sure.

Comment: don't worry. I understand you. It is a problem of stack exchange that it cannot show exact time of the answer. Thanks.